# How to compare mysql date field with today +30 days using interval

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check if invoices sent on a particular date are due for a reminder. The reminder should occur 30 days after the invoice was sent, so I need to check if the invoice date stored in my database is more than 30 days older than todays date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
'SELECT * FROM tbl_invoices WHERE sent = 1 AND status <> 1 AND invoicedate < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY'
```

but this isn't giving me what I want. I know I need to be using INTERVAL for this calculation, but I'm not getting my head around it!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query into

```
'SELECT * FROM tbl_invoices WHERE sent = 1 AND status <> 1 AND invoicedate < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))'
```